Why does my typed racket code signal any-wrap/c: contract violation expected: acyclic value?
In my Typed Racket program, I'm seeing this error:
any-wrap/c: contract violation
  expected: acyclic value
  given: #0=(foo #0#)
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:

What could cause this error?

This error is hard to diagnose, because it's usually not at all clear what any-wrap/c has to do with the code that's signalling the error.
The problem here has to do with the way that casts are handled in Typed Racket. Specifically, a value that's passed with type Any (which is most commonly the result of passing a Typed Racket value to untyped Racket) can pick up a contract wrapper, any-value/c. If this value is cyclic (that is, there is a cycle of references within the value), the any-wrap/c contract may fail. Here's an example. This code actually uses the Any type directly, rather than passing a value to untyped Racket.
#lang typed/racket

(require typed/rackunit)

(struct foo ([a : Any]) #:transparent #:mutable)

;; create a cyclic 'foo' structure
(define (make-cyclic-structure)
  (define my-foo (foo 13))
  (set-foo-a! my-foo my-foo)
  my-foo)

;; pass a foo as an Any, then cast it and extract the field:
(define (take-any [x : Any]) : Any
  (define its-a-foo (cast x foo))
  (foo-a its-a-foo))

;; this causes the problem:
(take-any (make-cyclic-structure))
;; but so does this:
(check-equal? (make-cyclic-structure) 1234)

In this case, there are a number of fixes for the first of the two problematic lines. The simplest is just to change the type of the input to take-any from Any to foo. Another one is to change (cast x foo) into (assert x foo?); it turns out that using assert can result in a value that isn't wrapped in the same way. You could also use something like
(match x
  [(foo a) x])

... which is a little clunky but gets the job done.
Repairing the second one (the use in a test case) can be done with e.g.
(check-true (equal? (make-cyclic-structure) 1234))

... which isn't as nice (the fail message is just going to report that it wanted true and got false), but still performs the right test.
